# Выходит ошибка в слове break

Tags: java, while, break

```java
public class LOader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int q = 0;
        while (q < 10) ;
        {
            System.out.println(q);
            q++;
            if (q == 5) break;`здесь выходит ошибка`
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: конечно текст ошибки не важен. это бесполезная информация наверняка

Answer (score 3):

Происходит скорее всего бесконечный цикл и зависание приложения как минимум в дальнейшем. А всё потому, что кто-то не работает в *IDE* и не смотрит на ошибки, которые она выдаёт. В частности вот это

```
while (q < 10) ;
```

равносильно

```
while (q < 10) {}
```

либо говорят, что `break` не может быть применён вне цикла. Почему так, опять же, написал выше

Comment: @AntonShchyrov окей. чуть изменил

Comment: спасибо )))))))

Comment: @user480217 пожалуйста! Знак "галочка" слева от ответа

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что `break` допустимо использовать только внутри циклов. А у вас цикл, из-за `;` содержит только один оператор - пустой

```java
while (q < 10) ;
//            ^^^
```

А последующий кусок `{...}` считается обычным программным кодом

Comment: благодарю )))))